# Get distinct ISO dates by days, months, year

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework, distinct

I want to get a distinct set of years and months for all document objects in my MongoDB.

For example, if documents have dates:

- 2015/08/11
- 2015/08/11
- 2015/08/12
- 2015/09/14
- 2014/10/30
- 2014/10/30
- 2014/08/11

Return unique months and years for all documents, ex:

- 2015/08
- 2015/09
- 2014/10
- 2014/08

**Schema snippet:**

```
var myObjSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        date: Date,
        request: {
           ...
```

I tried using `distinct` against schema field `date`:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('date', {}, {})
```

But this gave duplicate dates. Output snippet:

```
ISODate("2015-08-11T20:03:42.122Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-11T20:53:31.135Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-11T21:31:32.972Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-11T22:16:27.497Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-11T22:41:58.587Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-11T23:28:17.526Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-11T23:38:45.778Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-12T06:21:53.898Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-12T13:25:33.627Z"),
ISODate("2015-08-12T14:46:59.763Z")
```

So the question is:

- a: How can I accomplish the above?
- b: Is it possible to specify which part of the date you want distinct? Like `distinct('date.month'...)`?

---

EDIT: I've found you can get these dates and such with the following query, however the results are not distinct:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate( 
     [ 
         { 
             $project : { 
                  month : { 
                      $month: "$date" 
                  }, 
                  year : { 
                      $year: "$date" 
                  }, 
                  day: { 
                      $dayOfMonth: "$date" 
                  } 
              }
          } 
      ] 
  );
```

Output: duplicates

```
{ "_id" : "", "month" : 7, "year" : 2015, "day" : 14 }
{ "_id" : "", "month" : 7, "year" : 2015, "day" : 15 }
{ "_id" : "", "month" : 7, "year" : 2015, "day" : 15 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to group your document after the projection and use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) accumulator operator

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
         "year": { "$year": "$date" }, 
         "month": { "$month": "$date" } 
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "distinctDate": { "$addToSet": { "year": "$year", "month": "$month" }}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you can distinct values via a `$group`/`_id: null`/[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) stage.

I'm also including here the use of [`dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) that formats your dates into `"%Y-%m"` (e.g. `2021-12`).

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-05") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-08") }
// { date: ISODate("2022-04-05") }
// { date: ISODate("2022-12-14") }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    months: { $addToSet: { $dateToString: { date: "$date", format: "%Y-%m" } } }
  }}
])
// { _id: null, months: ["2021-12", "2022-04", "2022-12"] }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
[
{
"$project": { 
                     "year": { "$year": "$date" }, 
                     "month": { "$month": "$date" }
            }
},{ $group : { 
                    "_id" :{"year" : "$year"  }
               }
},
{
$sort: {'_id': -1
}
   }
])
```