# Query for set of records given a month/year (NOT ISO DATE)

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to pass unique dates of n (lets say 2000+ records) to frontend, give users a list of `mm/yyyy` to choose the records by month.

Then I need it pass their selected month as the ID (currently format of `mm-yyyy`) to backend, and then query for only that set of records in that month/year.

I was able to get all distinct months/years for all records. But now I need to pass the `month/year` as a parameter.

**My question is:** How can I query for all records that match a given month/year?

I posted about something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109897/get-distinct-iso-dates-by-days-months-year/33110212?noredirect=1#comment54037111_33110212) earlier, where user3100115 recommended using [$redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/).

Docs say to pass in a year, `{ $match: { year: 2014 } },` and I'm assuming you can do this with month too. But then didn't really understand the "redact" portion of it.

So I just tried getting all records using the $match and year:

`db.mycollection.aggregate( { $match: { year: 2015 } } );` which returned nothing because I don't have a simple `year` field in my document... rather a `date` with format ISO.

---

I've tried

```
    var query = Order.aggregate(
        {
            $project:
            {
                year :
                {
                    $year:  '$date'
                },
                month:
                {
                    $month: '$date'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $match:
            {
                year : year,
                month: month
            }
        }
    );
```

But this doesn't return the document objects, only the _id, month, year:

```
  { _id: 'someid',
    year: 2015,
    month: 3 },
  { _id: 'someid',
    year: 2015,
    month: 3 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to take out the year and month from your ISODate field using [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). Then you could do a [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on the projected values. Something like below might give you an idea.

$created_at is an ISODate field in MongoDB.

```
db.test.aggregate(
 { "$project": {
      "year":{"$year":"$created_at"},
      "month":{"$month":"$created_at"},      
 },
 { "$match":{ 
      "year" :2015,
      "month": 3       
   }
 })
```

If you need more fields to the returned result, you can add those fields to the project or else try with the mongodb [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause.

```
db.test.find({$where : function() { return (this.date.getMonth() == 11 && this.date.getYear() == 2014)} })
```

Note: Using $where might be very slow.

Comment: Awesome, but how can I get the actual document objects from this. It's only returning an object of _id, month, year.

Comment: Just added some more info. See if that helps.

Comment: Turns out to get the full document object, u can do `document: "$$ROOT"`

Comment: Yes, we can do that as well. Could you edit the answer and add it?

Comment: Actually I prefer to specify the fields :D THanks!

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned the best way to do this is using the [`$redact`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator.

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$and": [ 
                { "$eq": [ { "$year": "$date" }, 2015 ] }, 
                { "$eq": [ { "$month": "$date" }, 3 ] }
            ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
         ] } 
    }
])
```

Comment: Why is this better than the option above?

Comment: Because you only have on stage which makes it faster. the `$redact` operator is doing the `$project` and  `$match`  behind the scenes. Also don't use the `$where`